# C strange shifting behaviour

Tags: c, bit-shift

The following line:

```
printf("%ld\n", ((long) 7 << 63) >> 63));
```

Outputs **-1**

I've checked and

```
sizeof(long) == 8
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: I was expecting 1. I want to keep the first bit.

Comment: You are shifting the 0 bit with value 1 into the sign bit. When you shift it all back, the sign bit is preserved, so a 1 is always shifted out, resulting in a value with all bits set, or `-1`. This is why it is Undefined Behaviour to shift a signed value like this.

Answer (score 1):

```
((long) 7 << 63) >> 63)
```

invokes undefined behavior as `(long) 7 << 63` is not representable in a `long`.

Comment: printf("%ld\n", ((long) ((long)7 << 63)) >> 63); //still gives me -1

Comment: `(long) 7 << 63` is undefined behavior.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood. Now I got it, I'll use unsigned long.

Comment: What you would like to do is: `printf("%llu\n, ((unsigned long long) 7 << 63) >> 63))`.